Nextjs Client and Server component conflicts
I am having a component that uses async\await and also usestate. As far asI understand async\await can be used in server component only and Usestate only in client component.I am using Next.js. This is to add form data to local json. For Usestate if I make it client using 'use client' , gives error saying async\await is for server component only.
I am referencing this component from the page.tsx 
const ADD_USER = gql`
  mutation AddUser($input: AddUserInput!) {
    addUser(input: $input) {
      id
      name 
      email
    }
  } 
`;

// 2. Create Form Component
const AddUserForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const [addUser] = useMutation(ADD_USER);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await addUser({
        variables: {
          input: {
            name,
            email,
          },
        },
      });

      // Optionally, update local JSON file with the new data
      // This could involve reading the JSON file, adding the new data, and writing it back to the file
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding user:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Add User</button>
    </form>
  );
};

// 3. Render the Form Component in your Next.js page
const AddUser: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add User</h1>
      <AddUserForm />
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddUser;


Split it in 2 components. 1 for async/await and 1 for holding the state

Can you please show an example ? I am new and totally lost with all these.
